# CardView Doesn't Appear On Nexus5

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, android-cardview

I have been using `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` in my application and something funny is happening.

I don't see the CardView's in the IDE preview but they show up on all the various devices that my app is running on, such as:

- Samsung (GS III and IV)
- Moto G
- OnePlus 1

But when running on Nexus 5 (which is running Android 5.0) the CardViews don't show as if they aren't even there, but what's inside them is shown.

Does anybody know why that is? I haven't been able to find the reason looking online yet.

Here's the XML of my CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        cardView:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="2dp"
        cardView:cardElevation="5dp"
        cardView:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

The `Padding` and the `Elevation` don't seem to be working either

Comment: Why are you using two different references card_view and cardView in your xml ? Whats the difference here ?

Comment: that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: No that was a typo on stackoverflow not on android

Answer (score 0):

Use `cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` in `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

Comment: Thanks is this supposed to fix the IDE rendering issue too? Cuz it didn't

Comment: I don't think it effects what's shown in the preview.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem on an actual phone either!

Comment: Post the XML code for your `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

Comment: Just updated the question with the code. Having the padding there doesn't make a difference

Comment: Try adding an elevation.

Comment: That didn't work either! I added the elevation in the code up there

Comment: try `android:elevation` as well.

Comment: No resource identifier found for attribute 'elevation' in package 'android'